# Murder has repercussions, how do I fix my reputation?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

So I was a bit zealous in the murdering of some Nobles and now I have guards attacking me on sight in Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition. How can I improve my reputation? And is there any solution to already spawned hostile guards in Nashkel wanting to kill me? I know I could just kill them, but that also hurts my reputation causing a spiral of negative reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to improve reputation is to donate at temples. The other option would be to do certain quests, which influence reputation.

[The wiki](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/Reputation) has a detailled cost breakdown for buying reputation up as well as a list of subquests influencing reputation.

As for the guards (flaming fist soldiers), they should disappear or become neutral, once your reputation recovered. But I cannot say for certain.

Comment: The guards do not appear to be despawning even after getting my reputation back up to 9.

Comment: If they neither despawn nor turn non-hostile once you reached a rep of 7 and left the area for a while, then it seems, they'll stay hostile forever. Which is weird, but it seems you can only avoid them then. Killing them would plummet your rep down again and likely spawn a new group, unless you can find a temple in the same area.

Comment: I was able to use charm person to let them kill each other (no influence hit). Then I kited the last one into the wilderness and just took the rep hit.